# CF query issue involving users and locations

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, group-by, cfquery

I am trying to figure out the best way to properly set up my queries. Basically I have a mini form asking `location` `EmployeeName` `StartDate` and `EndDate`. I am using two MS SQL Server tables unfortunately on two different servers that I am unable to link.

My goal is to have 5 columns 
 Associate Name | Location Name | Associate Checklists for location | Total Location Checklists | Associate Percentage

The main table I am using is cl_checklists: the three columns I am using are `date` to check the dates between selected on the form, `associate` for the EmployeeNames and `trans_location` for the different locations.

```
    <cfset result = {} /> 
<cftry> 
    <cfset date1 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.StartDate & '00:00:00')>
    <cfset date2 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.EndDate & '23:59:59')>

    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetEmployeeInfo">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    cl_checklists
        WHERE   date >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND date <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
                AND associate IN ( <cfqueryparam value="028,998,28" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
    </cfquery>

     <cffunction name="getop_id" access="public" returntype="string"> 
        <cfargument name="associate"  > 
        <cfquery name="spitOutop_id" datasource="#application.userinfo_dsn#"> 
            SELECT assoc_name 
            FROM dbo.tco_associates 
            WHERE assoc_id= #arguments.associate# 
        </cfquery> 
        <cfreturn spitOutop_id.assoc_name > 
     </cffunction> 

<table border="1" id="Checklist_Stats">
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Associate Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Associate</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Selected Location(s)</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Associate Percentage of Location Total</strong></th>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <cfquery name="allAssociatesQry" dbtype="query">
        SELECT DISTINCT associate, COUNT(*) AS associateCount FROM GetEmployeeInfo GROUP BY associate ORDER BY associate 
    </cfquery>
      <cfloop query="allAssociatesQry">
        <cfset thisAssociateName = trim(allAssociatesQry.associate) />
      <cfquery name="allLocCodeForAssociateQry" dbtype="query">
          SELECT trans_location,count(trans_location) AS locCntr FROM GetEmployeeInfo WHERE associate='#thisAssociateName#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
      </cfquery>
        <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForAssociateQry">
          <tr>
              <td><strong>#thisAssociateName#</strong></td>
              <!---<td><strong>#getop_id(192)#</strong></td>--->
              <td>#allLocCodeForAssociateQry.trans_location#</td>
              <td>#allLocCodeForAssociateQry.locCntr#</td>
              <td>#allAssociatesQry.associateCount#</td>
              <td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForAssociateQry.locCntr/allAssociatesQry.associateCount) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
          </tr>
          <cfset thisAssociateName = "" />
      </cfoutput>
      </cfloop>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<cfcatch type="any"> 
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message > 
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail > 
    </cfcatch> 
</cftry>
```

[image]

I cannot figure out how to change my query for the 4th column the total is showing the users total checklist for that location but instead I want the total checklists for the location in the 4th column. Will someone please tell me where I am going wrong and how I can find the total of that locations instead of the users total at that location which is already the third column.

Can i do a query inside a query like add

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    cl_checklists
        WHERE   date >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND date <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
    </cfquery>
```

and then do a total count adding another output inside the loop?

Comment: Anytime I see query inside of a `<cfloop>` I get dizzy. Is it possible to round up all the data via single query? Perhaps with a JOIN?

Comment: Why are you unable to link the two database servers?  Technically, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `allAssociatesQry` for your 4th column **'Checklist Generated By Selected Location(s)'** which is grouped by `associate` but you want the total checklist count in your 4th column here to be Grouped on `Location` and not `Associate`.

You might want to consider separating them!

Keep the code as is, just add a separate query for calculating the 4th column just after the `allLocCodeForAssociateQry` query:

```
<cfquery name="allLocCountForAssociateQry" dbtype="query">
    SELECT trans_location,count(trans_location) AS totalLocCount FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location IS NOT NULL AND trans_location IN (#QuotedValueList(allLocCodeForAssociateQry.trans_location)#) GROUP BY trans_location
</cfquery>
```

And now use the filtered value from this query inside your `cfoutput` query loop for `allLocCodeForAssociateQry` like this:

```
<cfoutput query="allLocCodeForAssociateQry">
  <tr>
      <td><strong>#thisAssociateName#</strong></td>
      <!---<td><strong>#getop_id(192)#</strong></td>--->
      <td>#allLocCodeForAssociateQry.trans_location#</td>
      <td>#allLocCodeForAssociateQry.locCntr#</td>
      <!--- Change 4th column to: --->
      <td>#allLocCountForAssociateQry['totalLocCount'][CurrentRow]#</td>
      <td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForAssociateQry.locCntr/allAssociatesQry.associateCount) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
  </tr>
  <cfset thisAssociateName = "" />
</cfoutput>
```

### Update:

David, based on the discussion we had over chat, where you mentioned that you want to show the total for each Associate group result and you want an aggregate of the result at the end of the report.

Based on this, I am posting one of the solutions **note**: I believe that using grouping in `cfloop` would result in more simplified and optimal result, but for time's sake I chose to go with the current working solution.

I have also added bunch of comments to make it more readable and clear.

**Here is the solution:**

```
<cfset result = {} /> 
<cftry> 
    <cfset date1 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.StartDate & '00:00:00')>
    <cfset date2 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.EndDate & '23:59:59')>

    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetEmployeeInfo">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    cl_checklists
        WHERE   date >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND date <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
                AND associate IN ( <cfqueryparam value="028,998,28" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT  *
        FROM    cl_checklists
        WHERE   date >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND date <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
                AND trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
    </cfquery>

     <cffunction name="getop_id" access="public" returntype="string"> 
        <cfargument name="associate"  > 
        <cfquery name="spitOutop_id" datasource="#application.userinfo_dsn#"> 
            SELECT assoc_name 
            FROM dbo.tco_associates 
            WHERE assoc_id= #arguments.associate# 
        </cfquery> 
        <cfreturn spitOutop_id.assoc_name > 
     </cffunction> 

     <cfquery name="allAssociatesQry" dbtype="query">
        SELECT DISTINCT associate, COUNT(*) AS associateCount FROM GetEmployeeInfo GROUP BY associate ORDER BY associate 
     </cfquery>

<table border="1" id="Checklist_Stats">
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Associate Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Associate</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Selected Location(s)</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Associate Percentage of Location Total</strong></th>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!--- aggregate variables --->
      <cfset aggrAssociateChecklist = 0>
      <cfset aggrLocationChecklist = 0>

      <cfloop query="allAssociatesQry">
          <!--- get Associate's name --->
          <cfset thisAssociateCode = trim(allAssociatesQry.associate)>
          <cfset thisAssociateName = getop_id(thisAssociateCode) />
          <!--- 1.1 get all trans_location code and total counts for the current Associate --->
          <cfquery name="allLocCodeForAssociateQry" dbtype="query">
              SELECT trans_location,count(trans_location) AS locCntr FROM GetEmployeeInfo WHERE associate='#thisAssociateCode#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
          </cfquery>
          <!--- 1.2 get the aggregate of checklist count generated by the current Associate for each location --->
          <cfquery name="qTotalChecklistCountForAssociate" dbtype="query">
              SELECT SUM(locCntr) AS totalAssocChecklist FROM allLocCodeForAssociateQry 
          </cfquery>

          <!--- 2.1 get the total location checklist for each location available for the current Associate --->
          <cfquery name="allLocChecklistForAssociateQry" dbtype="query">
              SELECT trans_location,count(trans_location) AS totalLocCount FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location IN (#QuotedValueList(allLocCodeForAssociateQry.trans_location)#) GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
          </cfquery>
          <!--- 2.2 get the aggregate of location checklist generated by the current Associate --->
          <cfquery name="qTotalLocChecklistForAssociate" dbtype="query">
              SELECT SUM(totalLocCount) AS totalLocChecklist FROM allLocChecklistForAssociateQry
          </cfquery>
          <!--- display record for the current Associate --->
            <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForAssociateQry">
              <tr>
                  <!---<td><strong>#thisAssociateCode#</strong></td>--->
                  <td><strong>#thisAssociateName#</strong></td>
                  <td>#allLocCodeForAssociateQry.trans_location#</td>
                  <td>#allLocCodeForAssociateQry.locCntr#</td>
                  <td>#allLocChecklistForAssociateQry['totalLocCount'][CurrentRow]#</td>
                  <td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForAssociateQry.locCntr/allLocChecklistForAssociateQry['totalLocCount'][CurrentRow]) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
              </tr>
              <cfset thisAssociateName = "" />
            </cfoutput>
            <!--- 3.1 get sub total for each Associate group --->
            <cfset totalAssocChecklist = qTotalChecklistCountForAssociate.totalAssocChecklist>
            <cfset totalLocChecklist = qTotalLocChecklistForAssociate.totalLocChecklist>
            <!--- 3.2 add to the aggregate --->
            <cfset aggrAssociateChecklist += totalAssocChecklist>
            <cfset aggrLocationChecklist += totalLocChecklist>
            <!--- display sub total for each Associate group --->
            <cfoutput>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Subtotal</strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>#totalAssocChecklist#</td>
                    <td>#totalLocChecklist#</td>
                    <td>#NumberFormat((totalAssocChecklist/totalLocChecklist) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
                </tr>
            </cfoutput>
      </cfloop>
      <!--- display calculated aggregate at the end of the result --->
      <cfoutput>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>#aggrAssociateChecklist#</td>
            <td>#aggrLocationChecklist#</td>
            <td>#NumberFormat((aggrAssociateChecklist/aggrLocationChecklist) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
          </tr>
      </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
</table>
<cfcatch type="any"> 
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message > 
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail > 
    </cfcatch> 
</cftry>
```

Comment: ah! I guess you'll have to match the order for displaying your city codes and order of the `totalLocCount` to be the same.

Comment: I meant the same @DavidBrierton. Can you post the new query result for better understanding?

Comment: @DavidBrierton I just updated my answer to include the changes you wanted for your resultset as we'd discussed over chat.

Comment: Hi @DavidBrierton I have corrected the solution. Check the result again.

Comment: @DavidBrierton If the solution worked for you as you mentioned in the chat conversation, please marked it as accepted.